# where I will get post webservice url of json type

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, blackberry

I am learning how to  post json data and get response.Is there any web service url available for post resquest like.
I am setting data in json format and get response in json format ?

Thanks

Comment: already try ..I got some service in which I am not passing any data

Comment: I need some url where I will pass data

Answer (score 1):

This service may be helpful, particularly the MD5 call in which you send and receive data

http://www.jsontest.com/

Comment: That's awesome... I just google-searched a few times for online json feedback services, that didn't come up... Probably because I assumed the service would be described as "feedback".

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly - here are some services I found:

- GeoNames http://www.geonames.org/export/JSON-webservices.html
- jsontest http://www.jsontest.com/
- Programmableweb - search for webservices http://www.programmableweb.com/apis/directory/1?format=JSON

I hope any of these links could help you.